# Android Layout - Creating a Chatting Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently I'm working on a thesis about android and gcm.

I'm trying to create this layout in android

[image]

but my project keeps on crushing.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#888888" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <Button android:text="@string/send" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Error Log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gcmchatting/com.example.gcmchatting.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #21: You must supply a layout_height attribute.   

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)   
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)    
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)   
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)     
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)      
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)      
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)     
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)     
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #21: You must supply a layout_height attribute.   
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)   
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5457)   
at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5592)    
at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1809)  
at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1721)     
at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)    
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)    
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)     
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)    
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)      
at com.example.gcmchatting.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)      
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)   
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)   ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <EditText 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send" />
```

Please add layout:heigth and layout:width parameter in edittext and also button view.
so i hope its useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You must have to add `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attribute to every XML `View`. In your XML, you didn't add height attribute to `EditText` and both height and width to `Button`. So, add them as follows...

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/send" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
    android:background="#888888" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="Send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="#26000000" />
```